# Is there an isomorphism between these two groups?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, group-isomorphism

[Z6,+6] Z6={0,1,2,3,4,5},+6 is addition mod 6.

[S6,o] S6 is a permutation group.

Is there an isomorphism between these two groups?

I have no ideas to figure out isomorphism between such two groups.
Thank you!

Comment: What is the cardinality of each group?

Comment: The cardinality for Z6 is 6.

Comment: The cardinality for S6 is 6!

Comment: And do you think an ISOmorphism could exist between the two groups, then?

Comment: I actually don't know...

Comment: Well, an isomorphism is a homomorphism that is bijective. And there exists a bijection between two sets if and only if they have the same cardinality. Your two groups have different cardinalities, hence there is no bijection (and therefore, no isomorphism) between them.

Answer (score 0):

The more standard notation for the permutation group with six elements would be $S_3$, as there are $6=3!$ permutations of 3 objects. To answer the question suppose,looking for a contradiction, that: $$\phi:\mathbb{Z}_6\rightarrow S_3$$ is a group isomorphism. Since $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is abelian,and $\phi$ is a isomorphism we must have that $S_3$ is abelian. If you could find two permutations of $S_3$ which do not commute then that would contradict the existence of an isomorphism. Depending on what you have covered to write up a full solution you should show that any group isomorphic to an abelian group is abelian. Then explicitly find two elements of $S_3$ which do not commute.

Comment: I would ask the author for clarification of what he means by $S_6$.  If he means the permutation group on six elements, you have answered a harder question than he asked.  If he means the permutation group on three elements, this is a good answer.  Welcome to the site!

Comment: I appeared to have jumped the gun on that one. Thanks for the kind welcome.